# Cocoapods - Using older pod version after using latest

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to use Cocoapods for the first time.

I was using the latest AFNetworking version and changed to 1.3.3 to support iOS 5, now my project isn't building.

Error:
[image: Error Screenshot]

What I did:

- Updated Podfile
- pod install

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a line like the following at the top of your Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
```

The version number there should match the deployment target of your Xcode project. You might not have this set to 5.0 (assuming that's your target), it might be set to 6.0, or maybe this line is missing. See if adding this line takes care of it.

After you update your Podfile with this, run `pod update`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! They are both set to 5.0, this didn't work for me.

Comment: Are there any warnings showing for the project? Also, are you opening the workspace, or the project?

Comment: Also, you should make sure you have the latest version of Cocoapods!

Comment: I'm using the workspace. The screenshot I posted shows the only warning related to it. This one: could not create compact unwind for .LFB3: non-standard register 5 being saved in prolog

Comment: I'm using the latest Xcode and apparently I need to update Cocoapods

Comment: Ok, @Gavin. I'm now using Cocoapods latest version, and I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, would you mind giving my question a +1? So it gets more attention, thanks!